# In spring boot JPA, how to properly POST an object whose entity representation has a foreign key association to a different entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

If I have a entity that contains an object of an another class, for example a `Book` entity that has within it a `Publisher` entity that is associated as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="PUB_CODE", referencedColumnName = "PUB_CODE")
private Publisher pub;
```

Is this a secure/correct (I saw the correct data in the DB in this example, but not 100% sure if it would work in all cases) approach to post an object that has foreign key association in the database? I don't know if this is safe to do in terms of transaction atomicity or in terms of threading, or if it is efficient. Relevant code below:

**Book.java**

```
package app.domain;

/*imports*/

@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6902184723423514234L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique=true)
    private String bookName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int pageCount;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PUB_CODE", referencedColumnName="PUB_CODE")
    private Publisher pub;


    /*public getters and setters*/

}
```

**Publisher.java**

```
package app.domain;

/*imports*/

@Entity
public class Publisher implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4750079787174869458L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="PUB_CODE",nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String publisherCode;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String publisherName;

    /*public getters and setters*/

}
```

**BookRepo.java**

```
package app.service;

/*imports*/

public interface BookRepo extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT pb FROM Publisher pb WHERE pb.publisherCode = TRIM(UPPER(:pubCode))")
    public Publisher findPublisherByPubCode(@Param("pubCode")String pubCode);
}
```

**BookController.java**

```
package app.controller;

/*imports*/

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/books")
public class BookController {

    private BookRepo bookRepo;

    @Autowired
    public BookController(BookRepo bookRepo) {
        this.bookRepo = bookRepo;
    }
    //The ApiPathParam is for JSONDOC purposes
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<Book> create(@ApiPathParam(name = "book") @RequestBody Book book, @ApiPathParam(name = "pubCode") @RequestParam("pubCode") String pubCode) {
        // Assume exception handling
        Publisher pbToAttachToThisBook = bookRepo.findPublisherByPubCode(pubCode);
        book.setPub(pbToAttachToThisBook);
        bookRepo.save(book);
        return bookRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Post object body (input into a POST tool):**

```
{
  "bookName": "goosebumps",
  "id": 0,
  "pageCount": 332,
  "pub": {
    "id": 0,
    "publisherCode": "",
    "publisherName": "",
    "serialVersionUID": 0
  },
  "serialVersionUID": 0
}
```

**pubCode parameter input provided, also into the POST tool, in the same call as above**: 'SC'

After the above code was executed, in the Book table, there was an entry for the book above, with its `PUB_CODE` foreign key column filled in with `'SC'`,  and the returned `List<Book>` of the POST controller method that was called showed that the newly added book included the `Publisher` entity information (such as the full name "Scholastic") for publisher with `PUB_CODE='SC'` that was already existing in the database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique you posted originally (passing the FK ID, retrieving it manually in your controller, and setting it on the entity explicitly) is valid and secure.

I don't know of a cleaner approach unless you move to HATEOAS principals, which allows for resource link handling: http://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to `separate/decouple` your `data layer's domain model` from your `Rest Resources/ API specs`, as they could evolve at a different pace.  Also your choice of `JPA` should not influence the `API specs`.

Should this feel like something you want to pursue there lots of resources out there including [Best Practices for Better RESTful API](http://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/)

Comment: Please see my edit. I was under the impression this how the domain and services are to be separated. Is it wrong?